# Duplicate a line containing one or more instances of a variable and then replace that variable in the duplicated line

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm able to replace lines with a single occurrence of a variable using regex:

`(^.*)(OLD)(.*$)/$1$2$3\n$1NEW$3`

eg:

```
enum{ 
  OLD,
  END
};

char *const test_token[] = {
  [OLD] = "OLD",
  NULL 
};
```

would be replaced with

```
enum{ 
  OLD,
  NEW,
  END
};

char *const test_token[] = {
  [OLD] = "OLD",
  [OLD] = "NEW",
  NULL 
};
```

which is correct for a single occurrence of the `OLD' variable, but not with more than one.

I can see why the regex won't work for multiple occurrences, but I don't know how to improve it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm running in Netbeans, which can interpret regex for replace commands

Comment: Could you post which would be your desired output?

Comment: @davide The desired output is:

`enum{    
  OLD,  
  NEW,
  END
};`
  
`char *const test_token[] = {
  [OLD] = "OLD",
  [NEW] = "NEW",
  NULL 
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say how to do this in a replace dialog in your IDE.

With sed:

```
sed '/OLD/ {p; s/OLD/NEW/g}'
```

That won't work on older seds though, so a couple of alternatives:

```
perl -pe 'if (/OLD/) {print; s/OLD/NEW/g}'
awk -v "old=OLD" -v "new=NEW" '{print} $0 ~ old {gsub(old, new); print}'
```

Comment: Thanks, the sed solution worked, would be cool if you could do it natively in regex though.

Answer (score 0):

awk:

```
awk '1;gsub(/OLD/,"NEW")' input
```

your regex was also for replacement. If you only want the "native regex" it would be /OLD/, replacement would be "NEW".